# How I write user lockout in ASP.NET to a log?

Tags: asp.net, security

I need to write to the application log when a user is locked out in ASP.NET Membership

Comment: Do you use a custom membership provider?

Comment: no, just the one built into ASP>NET

Comment: @ScottandtheDevTeam : Which stage you need to log? At the time of user get locked or when user try log in?

Comment: I only need to log after 5 unsuccessful attempts and they get locked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(myLogin.UserName);
if(user != null)
{
     if (usrInfo.IsLockedOut)
     {
        //write log
     }
}
```